# Sign-in to B2C using either Personal or Work or School email address

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am currently working on a B2C setup for my company.

In our Azure AD account, I have an email, say myemail@mycompany.com, which has a password.

I also have a Microsoft Live account using the same email, myemail@mycompany.com, which has a different password.

I have created a B2C setup using the following documentations.

https: //learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-msa-app

https: //azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-setup-msa-app/

https: //azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-app-registration/

After doing the B2C set up,   I am able to obtain a link, below is an example.

https ://login.microsoftonline.com/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_signin1&client_Id=&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=form_post&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

In my Azure setup, I already have both emails (Azure AD and Microsoft Live) added to my list of users.

My problem is, when I use the link generated from my B2C setup,  it only seems to allow me to sign in using the Microsoft Live account (which has a different password from my Azure AD account).

Is there a way, or a configuration, which will allow my B2C setup to invoke the sign in page to choose either my Personal (Microsoft Live account) or  work or school (Azure AD) account?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, B2C does not properly support work accounts from AAD (ironic, eh?).  You're correct in that personal accounts from MSA work just fine.

In B2C, you can add "local accounts" as an IDP, which will allow users listed in your tenant to sign into the app. I can't actually recall if that local account option allows you to sign in with a work account in your B2C tenant. You could give it a try if that's what you need. Most people however need proper support for AAD tenants, where work accounts are a dedicated option on the "IDP selection" screen. B2C doesn't have that today.

I do have a scratched together sample .NET app on my GitHub that shows how you can add support for work accounts and B2C in the same app. It's not pretty, but it works.

As for the same email/different password problem. Even adding the above support won't help. We don't expect that users will really be able to decipher a "work Microsoft account" button from a "personal Microsoft account" button. So, we are doing work to eliminate these situations, by limiting the number of users who get into such a situation and by providing an account linking option for those that are.

We do plan to support AAD work accounts in the near future. Sometimes your own family members are the hardest to work with.

If you feel so inclined, you can add your feature requests to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c